# Is there something like a System Usability Scale (SUS) for customization?

Tags: sus, customizable

I am wondering if there is a way to measure the customization of a Software product.
To be honest I am not really sure how such a measure should look like, but maybe I can find some ideas here.

Comment: sure, simply measure before and after and compare

Comment: @Devin they're not looking to compare usability before/after cutomization. They want to measure how customizable something is.

Answer (score 0):

honestly, I don't know if there is already a methodology like SUS to measure a Software System but AFAIK everything goes around to measure degree of Customization. To measure the degree of Customization of software must be consider dimensions like: user satisfaction, individual impact, organizational impact and intended business performance improvement.

Here some links found that maybe come in handy, try also to make more research about degree of customization of ERP.

[link 1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016412121630022X)

[link 2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237087297_Measuring_the_Effect_of_Customization_in_Influencing_the_Success_of_ERP_Implementation)

[link 3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/customizations)

If anyone more informed would help would be really appreciate

Comment: Thanks for your Input. I already read the first two papers and it really seems like there's no stadard way to measure the degree of customization.